# Storing XML data in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a XML data in format:

```
<Display>
 <StoreCode>1234</StoreCode>
 <TerminalID>02</TerminalID>
 <TrnsNo>0123456789</TrnsNo>
 <Date>03-05-2013</Date>
 <Time>11:30</Time>
 <Vdtls>
  <VID>VVB0000015</VID>
  <VID>VVB0000016</VID>
 </Vdtls>
</Display>
```

I have stored this xml data in a column of a table.
Now I want to parse this XML and store it in another table that has structure.

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[temp_XMLreceivedData]
 (
[StoreCode] [int] NULL,
[TerminalId] [int] NULL,
[TransactionNo] [varchar](10) NULL,
[RequestDate] [date] NULL,
[RequestTime] [char](5) NULL,
[VoucherDetails] [varchar](10) NULL
 )
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: You'd have to use the XML functions that MySQL provides http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/xml-functions.html Posted as a comment because I don't have MySQL installed to test

Comment: I believe you have used the wrong tag. You say it is MySQL but judging from the `CREATE TABLE` statement, it is actually SQL Server.

Comment: Erik: Yes create table statement is of MYSQl as I am not aware of MYSQL and have to perform this thing mysql

Comment: @KapilSingh Please state clearly if this is MySQL or SQL Server and set the correct tags. You have tagged it SQL Server, and your `CREATE TABLE` statement looks like SQL Server, but the error thrown by @user1484563's code indicates that you are using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Code

```
insert into temp_XMLreceivedData
select 
a.b.value('(StoreCode/node())[1]','VARCHAR(10)') ,
a.b.value('(TerminalID/node())[1]','VARCHAR(100)'),
a.b.value('(TrnsNo/node())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') ,
a.b.value('(Date/node())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') ,
a.b.value('(Time/node())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') ,
a.b.value('(Vdtls/VID/node())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') 
from @XmlTbl.nodes('Display') as a(b)
```

Comment: its not working.... Query : insert into temp_XMLdatadetails select  a.b.value('(StoreCode/node())[1]','VARCHAR(10)') , a.b.value('(TerminalID/node())[1]','V...
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('(StoreCode/node())[1]','VARCHAR(10)') ,
a.b.value('(TerminalID/node())[1]','VA' at line 3
Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000

Comment: @XMLTbl is used for what purpose?

Comment: here is the table structure in which i have stored that XML:            CREATE TABLE test_xml
  (
 ID INT,
 xmldata TEXT
   )

Comment: @XMLTbl is a Variable of XML Type.. declare as follows

Answer (score 0):

I thing the whole code is as follows

```
declare @XmlTbl xml

select top(1) @XmlTbl=cast(cast(xmldata as nText) as xml) from test_xml

insert into temp_XMLreceivedData
select 
a.b.value('(StoreCode/node())[1]','VARCHAR(10)') ,
a.b.value('(TerminalID/node())[1]','VARCHAR(100)'),
a.b.value('(TrnsNo/node())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') ,
a.b.value('(Date/node())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') ,
a.b.value('(Time/node())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') ,
a.b.value('(Vdtls/VID/node())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') 
from @XmlTbl.nodes('Display') as a(b)
```

this code works for only one data. looping the table if you insert all data of data